# How should I use Perl URI class?

Tags: perl, oop, url

I need to handle some HTTP URLs in a Perl program, but I have doubts how should the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) class help me.

Particularly, I'd like the to use the `URI` class for resolving relative URLs and getting their components. However, the problems are:

1. I need a function to work with both `URI` objects and URI strings as arguments (or ensure only one gets passed)

   ```
   sub foo_string_or_url {
     my $uri = URI->new(shift);
   ```

   is that the right approach? I don't quite like it, because it stringifies the `URI` and creates new object unnecessarily.
2. Extract the components

   ```
   my $host = $uri->host;
   ```

   This is also problematic, because not all `URI`s have host, particularly, if someone passes garbage to the function, this will `die()`.
3. Resolve a relative URL

   ```
   my $new_url = URI::URL->new($uri, $base)->abs;
   ```

   IIUC, without the `->abs`, the result will still stringify to the relative URL (and will not work for `HTTP::Request`s), am I right? Also, is this guaranteed to return a `URI`?

How should I handle these problems? The possibilities are

- Use `->isa('URI')` and `->can("host")` all the time

  - Seems error prone and ugly to me
- Don't use `URI` class at all and parse URLs using regexes

  - I'd still rather use a library solution than debug my own
- Wrap `URI` operations in `try { ... } catch { ... }`

  - see the first point

Is there a sane, fool-proof way of using the `URI` classes? Something simple I haven't thought of (in the list above)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your question can be summarised: parameter validation is tedious, what do I do about it?

1. I don't like it, either. This is a matter of differing opinion among developers, other say *coercions* are better than sliced bread, especially when automatically done by Moose. I argue that allowing only one type of simplifies the program. Also, YAGNI applies in the vast majority of cases. Reject wrong types, employ a helper module such as [Params::Validate](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Params-Validate-1.06/lib/Params/Validate.pm)/[MooseX::Method::Signatures](http://search.cpan.org/~ilmari/MooseX-Method-Signatures-0.37/lib/MooseX/Method/Signatures.pm)/[MooseX::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/MooseX-Declare-0.35/lib/MooseX/Declare.pm) in order to avoid the manual checks as shown in your code samples.
2. This is the desired behaviour. Exception handling mechanisms let you write custom code appropriate for each situation. If you think it's not aesthetically pleasing, remove it and mind the consequences of letting exceptions go unchecked.

   ```
   use Try::Tiny;
   my $host;
   try {
       $host = $uri->host;
   } catch {
       warn "Could not determine host for $uri. Message was: $_. Retry/abort/ignore?\n";
       …
   };
   ```
3. Yes and yes.

Comment: The only questions not answered is "How should I handle these problems?", and the answer is "always call abs". It won't do anything if you already have a an absolute URI.